# Add MVC3 as a Prerequisite in a WebApp installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, asp.net-mvc-3, prerequisites

How do I add Asp.NET MVC3 as a Prerequisite in my Visual Studio Installer project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a custom before install step where you would manually check if the required assemblies have been installed. You may also check the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, you don't need MVC 3 to be installed on the host that you use. You just need to do it like we did back in the "old" days.

Check out this blog post by ScottGu on ["Running an ASP.NET MVC 3 app on a web server that doesn’t have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the link. Although I'm not trying to include/install MVC3 (or any of the other prerequisites that we have), but only check if they exist (and download them if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm gonna add another answer to address the question directly.

All you have to do is set `"Copy Local = True"` for the following referenced assemblies in your project:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

And the setup project will **automatically** add them as "project dependencies" and put them into the "bin" folder when the setup is run.